# Combinatorial question: How many ways to eat lunch?

Tags: combinatorics

Anna is trying to decide what to have for lunch in the cafeteria. She can choose 1 entree and 2 side dishes. There are 4 available entrees, and 8 available side dishes. How many different combinations are ossible for Anna's lunch?

Comment: can she skip lunch entirely, or choose less than 3 dishes, or choose a double helping of a dish?

Answer (score 3):

You have $4$ entrees to pick from, and you choose 1.
$$4\choose1$$
You have 8 side dishes to pick from, and you choose 2.
$$8\choose2$$
Put those together to get
$$\binom{4}{1}\binom{8}{2}=4\cdot28=112$$

Keep in mind that this assumes the two side dishes must be different. If they can be the same, then there are $8\choose1$ ways to pick a doubled up sidedish. You can add this to the original $8\choose2$ for all your side dish combinations, then multiply by your entree possibilities for a new answer.

Comment: Adding to this, they can be put together because these two event are independent of each other.

Answer (score 1):

If she must choose exactly $1$ entree and exactly $2$ **unique** side-dishes, then:

- Choose $1$ out of $4$ items: $\binom{4}{1}=\frac{4!}{1!\times3!}=4$
- Choose $2$ out of $8$ items: $\binom{8}{2}=\frac{8!}{2!\times6!}=28$
- So she can make $4\times28=112$ different combinations